# <head> and <body> validation issues

Tags: html, validation

I have what I thought was a pretty simple  area of my webpage, but it is failing validation from validator.w3.org and I cannot work out why.

The full source can be seen at http://iapps.smartphonesoft.com

The first part of the source is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!-- TradeDoubler site verification 1xxx -->
<title>iPhone Apps, iPhone Software and Freeware</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style2.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css"> 
/* place css fixes for all versions of IE in this conditional comment */
.thrColLiqHdr #sidebar2, .thrColLiqHdr #sidebar1 { padding-top: 30px; }
.thrColLiqHdr #mainContent { zoom: 1; padding-top: 15px; }
/* the above proprietary zoom property gives IE the hasLayout it needs to avoid several bugs */
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<?php
```

The errors I get are as follows, I guess it is something obvious that is staring me in the face but I am afraid I cannot see what!

> Validation Output: 3 Errors
>
> Line 35, Column 7: end tag for
>   element "head" which is not open
>    ✉ The Validator found an end
>   tag for the above element, but that
>   element is not currently open. This is
>   often caused by a leftover end tag
>   from an element that was removed
>   during editing, or by an implicitly
>   closed element (if you have an error
>   related to an element being used where
>   it is not allowed, this is almost
>   certainly the case). In the latter
>   case this error will disappear as soon
>   as you fix the original problem.
>
> If this error occurred in a script
>   section of your document, you should
>   probably read this FAQ entry.
>
> Line 36, Column 6: document type does
>   not allow element "body" here  ✉
>   The element named above was found in a
>   context where it is not allowed. This
>   could mean that you have incorrectly
>   nested elements -- such as a "style"
>   element in the "body" section instead
>   of inside "head" -- or two elements
>   that overlap (which is not allowed).
>
> One common cause for this error is the
>   use of XHTML syntax in HTML documents.
>   Due to HTML's rules of implicitly
>   closed elements, this error can create
>   cascading effects. For instance, using
>   XHTML's "self-closing" tags for "meta"
>   and "link" in the "head" section of a
>   HTML document may cause the parser to
>   infer the end of the "head" section
>   and the beginning of the "body"
>   section (where "link" and "meta" are
>   not allowed; hence the reported
>   error).
>
> Line 270, Column 7: end tag for
>   "body" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was
>   specified  ✉ You may have
>   neglected to close an element, or
>   perhaps you meant to "self-close" an
>   element, that is, ending it with "/>"
>   instead of ">".
>
> Line 17, Column 1: start tag was here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code at the link you provide, the problem seems fairly obvious -- you close the `<head>` element and open the `<body>` element twice:

```
</head> 
<body> <!-- first time -->


<script type="text/javascript"> 

  /* some script */

</script> 

</head> 
<body> <!-- second time! -->
```

Comment: agh! I knew it would be obvious, thanks alot, I had an include which had the second /head and body in it!!